# How to make my LLM powered chatbot using ChromaDb Faster?

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I am building a LLM powered chatbot. Using ChromaDb for searching relevant documents and then LLM to answer. Any method to get faster responses ?? Currently it takes around 15 seconds to answer. Around 8 seconds for ChromaDb to find relevant document and 7 to 20 seconds for LLM to answer. Any methods, techniques to make it faster ????

i Expected the speed of answering queries to be below 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

reduce the chunk size during data load.

```
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
```